# Enterprise report regular report

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am new to crystal reports. What is enterprise report? and how it is different from normal crystal report?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, there is no difference.

Semantically, if a report has been published to SAP's BusinessObjects Enterprise, it might be called an 'enterprise report'.  If a report is used throughout the organization, it might also be called an 'enterprise report'.